# command oriented linux drivers

Tags: linux-device-driver

How can i make my driver to act on following commands cat & echo.

Does cat call read() system call of a device driver ?
Does echo call write() system call of a device driver ?

I want to implement these two command cat & echo for my driver controlling 8 led.

If i echo it gives glows led 3  :-----

```
echo "3=1" > /dev/led_node
```

If i cat it gives following out-put status :-----

```
cat /dev/led_node
0 0
1 0
2 0
3 1
4 0
5 0
6 0
7 0
```

Please suggest what part or system call of driver interact with cat & echo system calls ?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily check how `cat` reads files using, for exampl, `strace`. Here is an example:

```
$ echo '123' >/tmp/test.txt
$ strace cat /tmp/test.txt
```

In the output, you can spot the `open()` call:

```
open("/tmp/test.txt", O_RDONLY)         = 3
```

Which returns `3` - a file descriptor associated with `/tmp/test.txt`. Further down the output, you can see:

```
read(3, "123\n", 65536)                 = 4
```

Which takes file descriptor `3` and reads from it (using a buffer size of `65536` bytes and getting back 4 bytes).  basically answers your first question - `cat` does call `read()`. You can do the same thing for `echo` and figure out that it calls `write()`.

In your character device driver, you would have to implement those calls. For a great explanation  on how it works along with useful examples, check out [Linux Device Drivers, Chapter 3](http://www.xml.com/ldd/chapter/book/ch03.html).

Hope it helps. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

**cat:** system call interacts with read function of your driver. **echo:** system call interacts with write function of your driver. Thing is if you cat on /dev/led_node, device file/node is opened i.e. calling open system call, then read system call is called, keeps looping in the read unless **zero** is returned (no data present to read) and atlast close system call is called, which close the device node/file.